# How to Insert records in multiple inter dependent tables in a Single SQL Transaction?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net, sqltransaction

I have a scenario where i need to perform `INSERT Operation` on multiple `SQL` tables, There is a dependency for inserting records in each table.

I want to perform first `INSERT` to Deal table and then list of contacts and companies to the respective tables, similarly for associated contacts and companies `INSERT`.

All `INSERT` operations should be part of one `SQL Transaction` so that there should be no orphan record entry in the database tables.

I am thinking to put all `INSERT` operation logic in a single `Stored Procedure` but don't have enough understanding of same for processing the list of records(*in case of contacts and companies*) from C# to SQL.

**Below is the Insert Table dependency criteria -**

*The main table => Deal ()*

- INSERT Deal (get INSERTED dealid to INSERT it in associated contacts
  and companies table)
- INSERT list of contact in Contact table (get INSERTED contactid to INSERT it in associated contact table)
- INSERT list of associated contact in DealContact table (dealid, contactid)
- INSERT list of company in Company table(get INSERTED companyid to INSERT it in associated company table)
- INSERT list of associated companies in DealCompany table (dealid, companyid)

**Question:** How to perform below SQL operations in single SQL transaction, to make sure there are no orphan record entries in the respective tables?

- INSERT List of contacts and then List of Associated Contacts for each deal
- INSERT List of companies and then List of Associated companies for each deal

**Below is the `C#` method where I am trying to put this Insert operations -**

```
public void ProcessDeals(List<Result> lstDeals)
{
    if (_objReq == null)
        _objReq = new RequestHandler();
    string strBU = string.Empty;
    foreach (Result deal in lstDeals)
    {
        #region Associated Contacts
        Task<AssociatedContacts> taskAscContacts = _objReq.Get<AssociatedContacts>(_limit, deal.id);
        //store response in a list of associated contacts
        List<AscContact> ascContacts = taskAscContacts.Result.results;      

        //pull cotact information from API using contact id
        List<Contact> lstContacts = new List<Contact>();
        foreach (AscContact contact in ascContacts)
        {
            Task<Contact> taskContact = _objReq.Get<Contact>(100, contact.id);
            Contact contactinfo = taskContact.Result;

            //store contact in list of contacts
            lstContacts.Add(contactinfo);   
        }
        #endregion

        #region Associated Companies
        Task<AssociatedCompanies> taskAscCompanies = _objReq.Get<AssociatedCompanies>(_limit, deal.id);
        //store response in a list of associated companies
        List<AscCompany> ascCompanies = taskAscCompanies.Result.results;

        //pull cotact information
        List<Company> lstCompanies = new List<Company>();
        foreach (AscCompany company in ascCompanies)
        {
            Task<Company> taskCompany = _objReq.Get<Company>(100, company.id);

            //store contact in list of contacts
            lstCompanies.Add(taskCompany.Result);
        }
        #endregion

        //TODO: finally db insert operations

        //Step 1 - Insert into deal
        //Step 2 - Insert into contacts
        //Step 3 - Insert into companies

        //Step 4 - Insert into Ass Contact 

        //Step 5 -- Insert into Ass company
    }
}
```

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: what are you using to insert into SQL Server? Entity framework, ADO or OLE?

Comment: @thepanch I am using ADO connection.